# Ommit the properties of a attribute in mapping class

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

Is it obligatory to specify all the propertis of a attribute like this

```
@Column(name = "ID_COMPANY", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

or make just :

```
@Column(name = "ID_COMPANY")
```

and for a string we have to specify a length ?

```
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 30)
```

or just :

```
@Column(name = "NAME")
```

Because if i change the length of `varchar` in my database i have to change it again at my mapping class and it's little hard if i have many changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not obligatory.

Most of these options other than `name` are used only if you use Hibernate to generate your database schema. If you maintain your schema manually, you can safely omit them.

However, some of them (such as `nullable` or `unique`) may be useful for documentation purposes.

Comment: thanks i used hibernate tools to generate mapping class ... how can i generate them again just with `name` option ?

Comment: @user3756879: I'm not familiar with these tools.

Comment: But i want to know if i have `varchar (20)` in my DB and `length=30` it will rise a execption ?

Comment: No. There attributes are only used when Hibernate generated the schema.

Answer (score 1):

All the elements of the `@Column` annotation have default values. Unless your schema goes against the defaults in nullability, uniqueness, length, etc. (or your DB column does not exactly match the name of your field name), you can leave them off the annotation to prevent clutter.

Defaults can be seen on the JavaDoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html